# Architecture advice on integrating.net & java application

Tags: java, .net, spring, jms

In one of our recent projects, we have decided to use a message based solution to integrate an existing .Net app to a new JAVA based application. There is a requirement to not use a Application Server. So I am trying to look into some alternative options. Currently we are planning to use ActiveMQ as the JMS provider. Also the Java application needs to interact with an backend database. So, when trying to figure out options, I found that the Spring framework would be quite helpful. It appears that Spring may need some additional components (e.g, Atomikos) to provide transaction support for JMS & JDBC operations.
I am trying to limit the user of additional components as much as possible.
So, Is this the right approach to use ActiveMQ with Spring. If so, can I just use the built-in transaction module available in Spring to support transactions?

Any advice would be very helpful?

Leo

Answer (score 1):

Use WebSphere MQ .NET interface (.NET native or XMS .NET) for sending/receiving messages from your .NET application. At the Java app end use MQ JMS interface. MQ JMS interface supports two phase commit, so you can synchronize your message gets and database updates.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the integration through MQ and WS. More tight coupling may lead to problems and complexity.

Comment: Does WS stand for Web service? Can you elaborate or share any links on this integration architecture?

Comment: MQ - Message Queue; WS - Web Services

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a messagequeue that has good .NET and Java clients - e.g. RabbitMQ That builds on AMQP. As well as serialization technology that has good cross-language capabilities (Thrift, Protocol-buffers etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at RabbitMQ